# W3C validator doesn't detect error in XML

Tags: xml, api, validation, w3c-validation

I'm working on a Java XML editor (for Android), and I started including the [W3C Validator API](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html#requestformat) .

I'm doing some tests on several files and stumbled across something weird with the following XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <child/>
```

As you can see, it's malformed (the root tag is not closed). When I use the [W3C Online Validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it detects the errors and prints

> Line 3, Column 13: end tag for "root" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

But when I use the API, the only detected errors are that the document contains no Doctype and the use of the self-closing tag.

Is there a parameter for the API to detect such an error?

Comment: I know this is generally not the kind of comment one seeks (at least not the one I seek) when asking a question but ...

Have you tried to set said Doctype first in case this error would prevent the detection of the not closed root node ?
I know this might sound silly since it detects the self-closing tag but just in case ?

Comment: I could, the problem is that I want to do this with user provided XML files, and most (if not all) of them aren't using Doctype at all. And I can't generate the Doctype myself, and providing a dummy Doctype will throw false errors.